# Set default value for radio button

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My buildForm class is like this below.

```
    $builder->add('icon','entity',
            array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:IconPics',
            'property' => 'label', // .. or whatever property the image location is stored.
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,        
            'label' => 'form.icon', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
             'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
                ->add('where', 'i.enabled = true');
             }
    ));
```

How can I set the default vaule for this radiobutton?

According to Peter Bailey's answer

```
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\IconPics;
//
$IconPics = new IconPics();
// howw can I select the target Icon?????
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the initial data for a form in a couple ways

1. With the **data** option

   ```
   'data' => $default
   ```

   Where `$default` is an instance of `UserBundle\Entity\IconPics`
2. Providing an initial data source

   ```
   // Assuming form is created in a controller
   $data = new WhateverYourEntitiyIs();
   $defaultIcon = new \UserBundle\Entity\IconPics();
   // Set properties on $defaultIcon here
   // or select $defaultIcon via the repository

   $data->setIcon( $defaultIcon );
   $form = $this->createForm( 'form_type', $data );
   ```

Comment: I am trying way 1. I made instance of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\IconPics. then How can I set the value of iconPics instance??

Comment: I can solve.     $query = $this->em->createQuery(
       "SELECT p FROM UserBundle:IconPics p WHERE p.id = 1");
     $defaultIcon = $query->getResult(); thanks!

Comment: The entity manager has a convenience method `find()` to do what you did with DQL above. `$defaultIcon = $this->em->find('UserBundle:IconPics', 1);`